# using pygame to stream over sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, pygame, webcam

I am working on with a webcam script I got of the internet in python and I am using pygame module the issue is that my webcam wil open and then the connection drops and says the socket is aready in use the server code is

```
import socket

import pygame

import sys


port=5014


#create pygame screen

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0)


while True:

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(("",port)) # server is available on the whole network by setting host to ""

s.listen(1)

connection, addr = s.accept()

received = []


# loop .recv, it returns empty string when done, then transmitted data is completely received

while True:

    recvd_data = connection.recv(1440021)

    if not recvd_data:

        break

    else:

        received.append(recvd_data)



dataset = ''.join(received)

image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(800,600),"RGB") # convert received image from string

#image = pygame.transform.scale(image,(800,600)) # scale image to 800*600

screen.blit(image,(0,0)) # "show image" on the screen

pygame.display.update()


# check for quit events

for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

        pygame.quit()

        sys.exit()
```

And the client code is

```
    import socket

    import pygame

    import pygame.camera

    import sys

    import time



   host = "localhost"

   port = 5014



   pygame.init()

   pygame.camera.init()


    cam_list = pygame.camera.list_cameras() # list available cameras

    webcam = pygame.camera.Camera(cam_list[0],(800,600)) # use first camera in list and set resolution

    webcam.start() # start camera


    while True:

    image = webcam.get_image() # capture image

    data = pygame.image.tostring(image,"RGB") # convert captured image to string, use RGB color scheme

    #print sys.getsizeof(data) # in case somebody wants to know the size of the captured   image


    # prepare for connection to server

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # TCP is used

    s.connect((host, port))

    s.sendall(data)

    s.close()

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The error I get on the server is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/s.py", line 20, in <module>
    s.bind(("",port)) # server is available on the whole network by setting host to ""
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in us
```

And the error I get on the client is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/c.py", line 45, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

And yes I have changed the port numbers does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the server you should create the socket only once (outside while), then `accept` multiple connections (inside while).

```
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("",port)) # server is available on the whole network by setting host to ""
s.listen(1)

while True:
    connection, addr = s.accept()
    received = []
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inside your first infinite loop, you are calling s.bind().  It works the first time but after that, the address is already in use and can't bind.

s.bind() and socket.socket should not be in a loop like that, they only need to be done once.  Then use the infinite loop to accept connections.